# How to organize OAuth logins and/API files.

Tags: api, oauth, openid

Before reading this, please note I am looking to know if anyone has figured out a better way to organize oauth logins and api authorizations . My oauths all work fine, but before I add more APIs I am wondering if anyone can help me get organized. I know this is not an easy question since you are not looking at my directories and code but I am hoping someone has run into this organizational problem. It gets messing since callback urls need to be in the root.

My site currently has the following oauth logins: T, Y!, G, FB - all working fine. My root is messy with a bunch of callback files that need to be in the root to work properly like: login-twitter.php, login-fb.php etc... and these files also have associated files such as kill-session.php and confirmation.php as well as directories that hold the 'required' files to make these oauths work.

Again, all my oauths use these two files along with the name-of-site-login.php.

```
#1 kill_session.php
#2 confirmation.php
```

Little Comparison between my T, Y! and Facebook oauth files

My Twitter oauth has something like 6 files and wonder if theses a better way.

```
#1 login-twitter.php
#2 getTwitterData.php
#3 /config/twconfig.php  
#4 /config/functions.php
#5 /twitter/twitteroauth.php
#6 /twitter/OAuth.php
```

Compare to Y!:

Yahoo

```
require yahoo/lib/Yahoo.inc
require config/functions.php
```

Compare to Facebook:

Facebook

```
require facebook/facebook.php
require config/fbconfig.php
require config/functions.php
```

Now, if I want to add some new API's i will be adding more callback files and its getting ugly. ugh, if anyone has a method to keep things organized that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the same callback URL for everything but with different parameters depending on the authorized application?

That way you could have http://www.yoursite.com/oauth-callback/?authority=twitter for your twitter callback. Then it is a matter of structuring your code and your persistence model instead of files.

Also, surely your callbacks do not need to be in the root to work properly?